# Laravel timedout queued job not firing failed method in job class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-queue

I have set up a basic laravel project with minimum configuration, mysql database, database queue etc.

I created a Job class with this content

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{

    public $timeout = 10;

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::info("Job started");
        sleep(12);
        \Log::info("Job ended");
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception){
        \Log::info("Job failed");
    }
}
```

And I fire the event from the route just for the sake of simplicity like this.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    dispatch(new \App\Jobs\TestJob());
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I have the php artisan queue:work running in the terminal and when I visit the base url route in the browser the job is queued up.

I get this as output for the queue:work command.

```
ajeesh@mymachine:/var/www/html/queue$ php artisan queue:work
[2017-10-05 10:28:43] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
Killed
```

When I checked the log file,

```
ajeesh@mymachine:/var/www/html/queue/storage/logs$ tail laravel.log 
[2017-10-05 10:28:43] local.INFO: Job started
```

It only has this content.

Because it get timed out after 10 seconds \Log::info("Job ended"); never gets executed which looks fine.

But, I wonder, why the failed event is not getting called.

I have made sure the requirements for the timeout are met

```
ajeesh@mymachine:/var/www/html/queue$ php -v
PHP 7.1.10-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2017 17:04:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.10-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

ajeesh@mymachine:/var/www/html/queue$ php -m | grep pcntl
pcntl
```

Can anyone help to understand what I could be doing wrong on this ?

Comment: Well basically the job has not failed (no unhandled exceptions or errors have occured)

Comment: You could use '$this->attempts()' to get the attempt number but I do not know if you could know if the previous had errors though

Comment: @ka_lin So you mean to say, unless I throw an exception in the Job class's execution, the failed method would not be called ? Do you have any suggestion :) how to make the failed method call with respect to the execution time of the job and timeout value ?

Comment: It should fail when it exceeds `$maxTries`, unless it is 0. https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/8076c61f51f01bb46f1e322a26325e3c4e35b7ae/Worker.php#L380

Comment: @AlexBlex It calls the failed method when $tries is exceeds the provided value, I thought it would behave the same for $timeout as well.

Comment: You are confusing `$timeout` and `$timeoutAt`. The former is used to kill the process, the later is to mark the job failed. Set `$timeoutAt` to `Carbon::now()->getTimestamp() + 10`.